# BelongsToMany Field not shown on create/update form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Can't get to work BelongsToMany field on Laravel nova.

**User.php**

```
public function places()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class, 'user_places');
}
```

**Place.php**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_places');
}
```

**user_places table**

```
id, user_id, place_id
```

**Nova/Place.php**

```
BelongsToMany::make('Users', 'users', 'App\\Nova\\User')
```

If I'll change BelongsToMany inside Nova/Place.php to BelongsTo, the field will appear, but after that I'll have an error related to not existing method ::uriKey();

Lots of people say that BelongsToMany field doesn't appear on update/create forms, but as I can see, they do - https://prnt.sc/lqliga

I'm using Laravel nova 1.2.0.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ? i am having the same issue